# turning 3 into 1000, 2 into 100 - getFixedDecimalValue function

Tags: javascript, math

I have written the following simple function which returns a number with a max of 6 decimal places:

```
getFixedDecimalValue(number) {
  let fixedDecimalValue = (((number *= 1000000) - (number % 1)) / 1000000);
  return fixedDecimalValue;
}
```

I would like this function to accept a second parameter which would dictate how many decimal places to calculate from then return that value (defaulting to 6 dp).

Something like:

```
getFixedDecimalValue(number, decimalPlaces = 6) {
  let fixedDecimalValue = (((number *= decimalPlaces) - (number % 1)) / decimalPlaces);
  return fixedDecimalValue;
}
```

**The Question:**
What is an elegant method of turning

```
6 into 1000000
```

Or the number

```
3 into 1000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function elegantMethod(number) {
  return Math.pow(10, number);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an easy to read solution which fits the purpose perfectly.

Comment: what about `const fancy = x => 10**x`?

Answer (score 1):

```
// x = integer
result = "1";

while (x--) result += 0;
```

or

```
result = 1;
while (x--) result *= 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method to `Math.pow` could be using `String#repeat` :

```js
const nZeros = n => +('1'+'0'.repeat(n));

console.log(nZeros(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to 'Programmer' for letting me know about `Math.pow`
Here is the working function which defaults to 6 decimal places:

```
getFixedDecimalValue(inputNum, decimalPlaces = 6) {
  let num = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
  let fixedDecimalValue = (((inputNum *= num) - (inputNum % 1)) / num);
  return fixedDecimalValue;
},
```